# User "votes cast" showing wrong period?

Tags: discussion, support

I checked my profile today, and could see the I'm a user of this site "since 9 months".

But, at the bottom right of the profile page, I see:[image: votes cast]

It shows 12, 4 and 2 under month, week and day respectively. What is that suppose to mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"month" shows the number of votes since January 1, "week" the number of votes since January 6, and "day" shows today's votes. All the dates are UTC based, which means the day starts differently from what you consider your day; even in UK, the day coincide just in a specific period of time (not when UK uses UTC+1 as timezone).

For the days between January 1, and January 5, the votes were:

- month: the votes since January 1
- week: the votes since December 30, 2012

This is because the week on Stack Exchange always starts on Sunday, midnight UTC.

Answer (score 1):

Those are the 'current' data for your voting statistics, it just means:

- This month in total you have cast 12 votes
- This week in total you have cast 4 votes
- Today in total you have cast 2 votes

Comment: I wish this site supported (facepalm). Feeling so stupid ;-)

Comment: @indrock It's not that clear when a week starts for Stack Exchange. (It starts on Sunday.) As side note, I once asked to a friend of mine (American) which one is the first day of the week, and she replied Monday, even if the American calendar shows Sunday as first day of the week. I take it is not that clear which one is the first day of the week. `:)`